# ASP.NET MVC Problem with Html.ListBoxFor()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems with the helper Html.ListBoxFor().

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class NewReservation
{
    public SelectList AvailableServiceDates { get; set; }
    public DateTime SelectedServiceDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my action method:

```
    public virtual ActionResult New()
    {
        NewReservation newReservation = new NewReservation();
        newReservation.AvailableServiceDates = new SelectList(nhSession.Linq<Service>().Select(x => x.DateTime).Distinct());
        return View(newReservation);
    }
```

And in my view:

```
<%:Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedServiceDate, Model.AvailableServiceDates) %>
```

Here is the exception:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   source
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot
>   be null. Parameter name: source]
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast(IEnumerable
>   source) +4177011
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.SelectInternal(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String optionLabel, String
>   name, IEnumerable`1 selectList,
>   Boolean allowMultiple, IDictionary`2
>   htmlAttributes) +723
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.ListBoxHelper(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String name, IEnumerable`1
>   selectList, IDictionary`2
>   htmlAttributes) +47
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.ListBoxFor(HtmlHelper`1
>   htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression,
>   IEnumerable`1 selectList,
>   IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +113
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.ListBoxFor(HtmlHelper`1
>   htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression,
>   IEnumerable`1 selectList) +85
>   ASP.views_reservation_new_aspx.__RenderMainContent(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\code\GTCC Culinary
>   Reservation\src\CulinaryReservation.WebMVC\Views\Reservation\New.aspx:11
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) +109
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +25
>   ASP.views_shared_site_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\code\GTCC Culinary
>   Reservation\src\CulinaryReservation.WebMVC\Views\Shared\Site.Master:66
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) +109
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) +208
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +56
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3060

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288729/mvc-listboxfor-raises-value-cannot-be-null-exception) describes the same problem. And like that post, if I change my NewReservation.SelectedServiceDate from DateTime to string, things seem to work. But everything I have read indicates this is a bug that should have been fixed in an MVC2 release candidate.

Am I doing something wrong? I don't want the property's type to be string, it needs to be DateTime. Shouldn't I be able to use objects that reflect my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A multiple select list could be empty (for example if the user makes no selection) meaning that you cannot bind to a value type (like DateTime). You could use a nullable `DateTime` instead:

```
public class NewReservation
{
    public SelectList AvailableServiceDates { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SelectedServiceDate { get; set; }
}
```

Also notice that in a multiple select list the user could perform multiple selections meaning that binding to a single date doesn't look very natural. IMHO it would be more natural to have this:

```
public class NewReservation
{
    public SelectList AvailableServiceDates { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> SelectedServiceDates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Changing the property to DateTime? worked. I don't want to allow multiple selections, so I changed to DropDownListFor() and passed in a size attribute.

Comment: @Ronnie, what you are looking for doesn't have an equivalent tag in HTML. In a `select` tag if you don't have the `multiple` attribute you can select a single option (renders as drop down), if you set the `multiple` tag, no matter to what value (even empty) you get a list box where you can always select multiple values. So, if you want a single selection use `Html.DropDownListFor`. Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-multiple

Comment: this explanation makes sense to me and why it works if you use a string instead of another data type: strings allow nulls.  I just wish that the listboxfor somehow prevented you from having that single selection.  It just isn't clear to use nullable or IEnumerable unless you are very familiar with HTML spec or MVC workings.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the SelectedServiceDate to something in your action method like DateTime.Now or something recent and see if that resolves the issue...  No date is being assigned, so that's DateTime.MinValue.