# Can someone help me Mock this ASP.NET MVC Controller with Moq, please?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, controller, moq

I'm trying to mock an `ASP.NET MVC2 Controller` using **Moq** but I get an error because i'm trying to mock *an non-overridable property*. How should I be doing this, please?

NOTE: the controller I'm trying to mock up is the (`abstract`) `ASP.NET MVC2 Controller` ... not a custom controller. Why? I'm trying to test some *custom controller extensions* I have made. I don't actually have a custom controller class.

Code:

```
// My own test helper magic shiz.
httpContextBaseMock = MockHelpers.GetAnHttpContextBaseMock();

controllerContextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContextMock.Setup(x => x.HttpContext)
    .Returns(httpContextBaseMock.Object);

controllerMock = new Mock<Controller>();
controllerMock.SetupGet(x => x.RouteData)
    .Returns(RestMockHelpers.MockRouteData().Object);
```

That last line fails with...

> System.ArgumentException : Invalid
>   setup on a non-overridable member: x
>   => x.RouteData

So then I thought, I shouldn't be mocking the `controllerContext`, but just creating an instance of it.. like what [REA_ANDREW did in his SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206921/how-to-mock-the-controller-context-with-moq) ...

```
var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(_httpContextBaseMock.Object, 
    new RouteData(), new Mock<ControllerBase>().Object);

var controller = new Controller(); <-- Cannot do this.
                                       Controller class is abstract.
```

So i'm not sure if I need to make my own fake controller class, in some test helper utility that does nothing, but just inherits from `Controller`. Then instantiate that.

But I feel that it should be all done using mock's, instead of starting out with some, then making some instances...

I'm so confused :(

---

Update:

I was asked to explain what code i'm trying to test. I've got a custom ViewResult i've made and the constructor set a single string property. I'm just making sure that property is set.

```
// Act.
var myResult = new MyResult(controllerMock.Object);

// Assert.
Assert.NotNull(myResult);
Assert.AreEqual("controllerName", myResult.ControllerName);
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are trying to test? Maybe there's an easier method.

Comment: Why not create a dummy controller class and use that for testing in stead of trying to mock it?

Comment: That's my question, Marnix. What's good practice, here? I feel that creating a dummy controller 'smells bad' .. and wanted to see what other people have done.

Comment: I don't see why creating a dummy controller would be a code smell. A mock is in fact a dynamically created dummy class. I've had to resort to dummy classes in some instances where overriding properties was not an option. I do tend to keep the dummy class with the test code (e.g. private class) to prevent maintenance issues.

Comment: Agreed - i keep them private, in the same file too. I've done it before - i was just curious to see if there's other ways to do it OR if i've missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tests, I create a test class controller inside the test class like:

```
protected class TestController : Controller { }
```

And then I have an isolated test class that I can use for the tests.  Then you can use this TestController instance.